# Error in names(dat) <- object$term : 'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0] in GAM model

Tags: r, gam

I am trying to run a GAM model but I am getting the next error:

```
    Error in names(dat) <- object$term : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

I found on the internet that this could be a problem of the package tor un gam (`mgcv`) reading Dates, but since I am not including this variable and this is a numeric variable should be not the problem.

In addition, it is worth mentioning that there are gaps in some variables, I dont know if this could create some issues.
My code:

```
ind_0.s = gam(ind_0. ~ s(year) +
            s(WGSn) + 
            s(WGSe) + 
            s(elevation) +
            s(NAO) +
            s(ratio_0.) +
            s(river, bs="re") +
            s(effort, bs="re"), 
          data = fish[fish$species=="Salmo salar",],
          family=nb(link=log),
          method="ML",
          select=TRUE)
```

Data I am using: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qR2mUdrpStOYBmxajc_F4nxS_qf-4bzf?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance for your help,

Answer (score 2):

One or both of `river` and `effort` are not coded as a factor (they are likely character vectors) and for the random effect smooth one or more of the covariates of the smooth *must* be a factor (otherwise using the random effect smooth doesn't make sense)

Comment: HI @Gavin, thanks so much for your help.  I changed both variables in "factor", but I got the same error message

Comment: I am getting the same error in the same context, using `newdata.guaranteed=TRUE` to ignore the random effect. Did you ever find a solution?